# Where Is Cortana Located (cortana.exe)

Tags: windows, vbscript, cortana

I want to make a "wake up word" for Cortana. I have a vbs script that listens for the word, "computer". I want it to start Cortana, but I am unable to find a conveniently labeled, "Cortana.exe" anywhere. Where is the batch file or exe or something? Or is this a horrible way to do it and I should use xyz?

Answer (score 2):

The location of Cortana contains some random characters so I can't tell you exactly where it will be. I can tell you that her real name is `SearchUI.exe`

To find your version of Cortana on your PC follow these steps:

1. Press `CTRL+SHIFT+ESC` to open Task Manager
2. Click `More details` to Expand to full view
3. Click the little Arrow `>` next to Cortana
4. On the second Cortana, inside the first Cortana, right click
5. Select `Open file location`

That will open Explorer to the correct folder. Inside that folder you will find all the Cortana files, including `SearchUI.exe`

All that being said, you can't just run that EXE to "wake up" Cortana. She's always running. You don't need to run her again.

To get Cortana listening you just have to press `WIN+C`. So bind your speech system to press those buttons to have the effect you want.

You can do this with software like VoiceAttack.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is already built into Windows.  Click Start and start typing `cortana` till you see "Cortana & search settings"  Select it and enable "Hey Cortana"

Comment: I mean to enable it from visual basic.

Answer (score -6):

STEP 1.
CTRL+ALT+DEL.

STEP 2.
GOTO USERS TAB, SELECT RUNNING/OPEN USER.

STEP 3.
RIGHT CLICK ON CORTANA, THEN SELECT "OPEN FILE LOCATION".

Comment: Why are you [shouting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBjoWXrbfYAhXjIsAKHdNVAdEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netlingo.com%2Fword%2Fshouting.php&usg=AOvVaw3NAGcOzvxSH6HZ_ykxwNtb)?